# Kernels of powers of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation and $dim(V)=n$. It is well known that there is an integer $m$, where $0\le m\le n$ such that
$$\{\textbf{0}\}=K(T^0)\subsetneq K(T^1)\subsetneq K(T^2) \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq K(T^m)=K(T^{m+1})=K(T^{m+2})=\cdots$$

Here $K$ denotes kernel.
Let the nullity of $T^i$ be $n_i$. Then we have a sequence
$$0, n_1, n_2, \cdots,n_{m-1},n_m,n_m,n_m,\cdots$$

Denote $s_i=n_i-n_{i-1}$, which can be thought of as how much "bigger" $K(T^i)$ is larger than $K(T^{i-1})$. It is clear that $s_i>0$ for $0 \le i \le m$.

I am reading a proof of some theorem and I think the author has implicitly assumed $s_{i-1} \ge s_i$.

I come up with a proof of this but am not sure about its correctness.

Consider $K(T^i)$. Since $K(T^{i-1})\subsetneq K(T^i)$, we can choose $s_i$ vectors, called $z_{i,1}, z_{i,2},\cdots,z_{i,s_i}$, all not in $K(T^{i-1})$ so that
$$K(T^i)=K(T^{i-1})\oplus \langle z_{i,1},z_{i,2},\cdots, z_{i,s_i}\rangle$$

Now consider the $s_i$ vectors $T(z_{i,1}),T(z_{i,2}), \cdots, T(z_{i,s_i})$.

First let us shown that they are linearly independent.

Suppose
$$\textbf{0}=a_1T(z_{i,1})+a_2T(z_{i,2})+\dots+a_{s_i}T(z_{i,s_i})$$
Then
$$\textbf{0}=T(a_1 z_{i,1}+a_2z_{i,2}+\dots+a_{s_i} z_{i,s_i})$$
$$\implies a_1 z_{i,1}+a_2z_{i,2}+\dots+a_{s_i} z_{i,s_i}\in K(T)\subsetneq K(T^{i-1})$$

Then by definition of $z_{i,1},z_{i,2},\cdots,z_{i,s_i}$, we must have
$$a_1 z_{i,1}+a_2z_{i,2}+\dots+a_{s_i} z_{i,s_i}=\textbf{0}$$
and hence
$$a_1=a_2 = \dots =a_{s_i}=0.$$

Now because
$$T^{i-1}(T(z_{i,j}))=T^i(z_{i,j})=\textbf{0}$$
we have 
$$T(z_{i,j})\in K(T^{i-1}).$$

Next, by the way $z_{i,j}$ are chosen, we have
$$T^{i-1}(z_{i,j})\ne\textbf{0}$$
$$T^{i-2}(T(z_{i,j}))\ne\textbf{0}$$
$$z_{i,j}\notin K(T^{i-2})$$

In conclusion, the $s_i$ vectors
$$T(z_{i,1}), T(z_{i,2}), \cdots, T(z_{i,s_i})$$
are linearly independent, $\in K(T^{i-1})$ but $\notin K(T^{i-2})$.

Hence,
$$s_{i-1} \ge s_i$$

Is the above proof correct?

Comment: Looks right to me. What are you unsure about?

Comment: Take care about permissible values of $i$. For example, $s_i>0$ assumes $m>0$, and $K(T)\subsetneq K(T^{i-1})$ assumes $i>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is correct. In fact, the number $s_i$ can be interpreted as the number of Jordan blocks of size $\geq i$ of the nilpotent operator $T|_{\ker(T^m)}$ from which it is clear that there are more blocks of size $\geq i - 1$ then blocks of size $\geq i$.